# Python dbconnection

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, dbconnection

I have a python code`(python 3.5.1)` in which I need to connect to `SQL server`. I am using the module '`pyodc`' but its throwing me an error

> "ImportError: No module named 'pyodbc'"

I am using `eclipse` on `Windows 8`.

Then I downloaded pyodc package from "https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc". I tried to install using `pip` first but its not working on `Windows 8.1`:

> "building 'pyodbc' extension error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat'.

Then I tried running `setup.py` file in the folder. But still i am not able to import pyodc module.

Can anyone help me in properly importing the module. I am very new to python and I know there might be some beginner mistake.

Comment: Look for a binary install package.The error is saying it can't find the file from the microsoft compiler that sets the path etc before compiling.

Comment: This page has links to binary installers for windows [pyodbc](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc)